# Displaying class contents in a GUI with Swing

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, data-binding, reflection

I have some classes with fields and getters/setters and I want to display the fields of the class in a Swing application.

The name of each field should be dosplayed in a `Label` and the value should be displayed depending on the type of the value, i. e. `String` uses a `TextField`, `List` uses a `ComboBox` and so on.

One difficulty is that the class can contain fields, which also need to be treated this way itself.

Is there a recommended/standard way of doing that?

I looked a bit into `java.beans` but I'm not really sure if it isn't primarily used when the class is a Swing component itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to use PropertySheet component from [L2FProd](http://www.l2fprod.com/common/index.php). From you description it should do exactly what you wanted.

It wasn't updated for a long time but works well.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an automated way to accomplish this. In fact I think you might even be approaching it incorrectly.  What if you List contains objects other than Strings for example, how is a JComboBox going to break this out?   I would suggest just using a `JTable` and putting the name in the first column and the value in a second column.

Answer (score 2):

You could add `@Annotations` to your fields you want to examine and display in the GUI. In every case you have to use reflections to access and find all the fields you want to display. I think you have to add a custom logic to the databinding which examines a given class for it's fields (maybe filtered with a `@Display` annotation or stuff like this).

This should be very easy to implement, you can rely on the POJO Bean definition and access all the fields over getter/setter, don't forget to cache the handled classes to avoid circular dependencies of classes.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is [ReflectionUI](http://javacollection.net/reflectionui/Getting-started.html). It can display primitive values objects and lists by just using reflection. It works well with getter/setter properties.

Comment: Don't provide only a link but please add some more details here.